# SSRS: paramters showing NULL by default

Tags: reporting-services

This is regarding parameter properties in SSRS Reprts.

problem definition:
I have created a SSRS Report and added a parameter using one of the columns on my dataset. And when I run the report, This parameter shows a list of values that includes a NULL value too.(I guess this parameter brings all the unique values from the source column) But when I query my source database, there were no NULL value to the column that is used as parameter.

1. I would like to know how a parameter is constructed? and how it is getting NULL values to display?
2. How can I avoid these NULL values in the list of values (when source itself does not have NULL values)?

Please help me,

Thanks in advance

Balaji

Comment: Adding `Where fieldname IS NOT NULL` to the SQL should solve the problem!

Comment: Is your data source a SQL database or a dimensional model? I ask because SSRS only creates datasets for your parameters when you work with models. And they behave very differently than SQL statements.

Comment: @StevenWhite - Yes my data source is a Tabular data model. I wonder how that NULL value is included in the list of values. Any clue ?

Comment: @MiguelH - Yes we can filter these NULL values at data set level. But I am worried how it impacts my result set. Since this is a tabular data model its not easy to track the result set unless like SQL Server database. So I am in search of the REASON why that NULL value is included.

Comment: @StevenWhite - Is it the behaviour of SSRS to add one Extra NULL to the list of values to the paratmeters we create?

Comment: You don't have to use the hidden datasets that it creates for you to get the Available Values for your parameter. You can add another dataset yourself, make it return a distinct list of the values you want, and use that instead.